# TreeMaps with java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap

I have a program that needs to use a map to store information about movies. Basically there are four or five categories, comedy action etc, and then the name of the movie. I tried assigning category to a key and having multiple values which are the movies but that doesn't work. I can use an arraylist to store an object that contains both fields and use a for loop to go through the whole list and use the objects get methods to see each value. How can I go about doing that with a map? What I need my program to do is ask a user for a category and then have a for loop go through the list and print out every movie with that category. Every time I try with a map it never prints anything out.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: why don't you use a map having the category as key and a list of movies as value. I suppose it should do the trick

Comment: Would using SQLite be an option for you? There are a few implementations for Java. Or must you absolutely use a TreeMap? If SQLite is an option, it may provide better scalability.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` where the `Integer` would represent the category and the `String` inside the `ArrayList` would be the movie names. Of course you could use other classes than Integer or Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

You could either map the movie name to the category:

```
Map<String, Category> movies;
```

Or you could keep a list of movies under a category:

```
Map<Category, List<String>> movies;
```

Overall, I would recommend indexing by something else, and keeping the information inside a `Movie` object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach:

```
enum Category {COMEDY, ACTION }

// class containing movie related information
public class Movie {
   private String name;
   // other useful fields

   // getter and setters
}

// ... your code containing the "movies logic"

Map<Category, List<Movie>> movies ...
```

Like this you can see the category to be used and extract the list for the given category. Even though a set would be a better container to keep the movies instead of the list...like that you avoid duplicates. Anyway, by using the interafaces (Set or List) would provide you more flexibility in picking later wathever implementation you would like...or even have it different for different categories for example: for Action LinkedList while for Comedy ArrayList.